# Is it possible to gather other apps data in swift?

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm building an web application with react-native.
In this app I need to gather some information about users.
One of them is how much time they spend on other apps installed on their phone.

I couldn't find any library for this job, so I've decided to write the native code my self.
For android, apparently there is this `UsageStatsManager` that can help me achieve what I want.

But when I searched for sth similar in ios, I found lots of old forums saying that this is not possible.

But I recently I saw this:

[image]

It is asking for permission to gather other apps data. SO IT IS POSSIBLE?

Any suggestion is appreciated. How am I supposed to this?

Comment: There is no API to do this. Instagram is talking about all the other ways it has built to track users, usually related to their frameworks, which third party devs voluntarily ship with their apps.

Comment: Thx for ur response.
Is it possible to clarify a bit more?

Comment: @ParsaArvaneh It means Instagram has built certain frameworks that sends data to their server, and third party that uses such framework in their apps will then send data to Instagram's server. Instagram is then able to use those data to collect how the user might have used their phone. They cannot get the data directly from their phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no API by apple itself for retrieving data of third party applications. This is called "Sandboxing" where applications are restricted from changing the device settings or retrieving/changing other apps data. Hence, why iphones are secure.

What you have shown in your screenshots is to track application data for personalised ads and such. This can be achieved using the `AppTrackingTransparency` framework provided by apple. You can read more about the framework [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apptrackingtransparency).

TL;DR - You can use `AppTrackingTransparency` for personalisation